# Ir a un componente específico al seleccionar un radiobutton

Tags: react-native

Necesito que al darle clic al radiobutton "persona juridica" me envíe al componente pagina4Screen pero no he logrado hacerlo.

```js
 <RadioButton.Group onValueChange={value => setValue(value)} value={value}>
      <RadioButton.Item label="Persona Natural" value="first" />
      <RadioButton.Item label="Persona Juridica" value="second"
            onPress={() => navigation.replace('Pagina4Screen')} />
    </RadioButton.Group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo adecuado sería manejar eso por separado, crear un estado que maneje eso y un effect que te lleve a la ruta al cambiar tu estado, ejemplo:

```
const [isNatural, setIsNatural] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
  if(!isNatural){
    navigation.replace('Pagina4Screen')
  }
}, [isNatural])
```

```js
 <RadioButton.Group onValueChange={value => setValue(value)} value={value}>
      <RadioButton.Item label="Persona Natural" value="first" />
      <RadioButton.Item label="Persona Juridica" value="second"
            onPress={(arrRbts) => {
              handleRadio(arrRbts)
              setIsnatural(false)
            }} />
</RadioButton.Group>
```